# In Wanted (2008), why was The Exterminator in the location where he got shot?

Tags: character-motivation, wanted

Rewatched [Wanted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wanted_(2008_film)) last night and noticed an odd bit.  While chasing Cross, Wesley quickly turns around and shoots someone behind him.  This turns out to be The Exterminator--the guy with who liked to feed the rat explosives and use them as bombs.  When The Repairman gets there, he is shocked to find The Exterminator, implying The Exterminator has no business being there.

The Exterminator mentions multiple times that Wesley's father had though about using thousands of rats in this way.  Later, when Wesley finds Cross's plans to attack the Textile Mill, it seems to involve using such rats.

So, why was The Exterminator there?  Specifically, was he working with Cross as an inside agent?

Comment: Been a bit, but I remember being curious about that scene as well. I think that is one of the things that ... "true fans" would understand, given the movie is based off of either a mini series or comics; I'm not sure which. It is possible there is a deleted scene as well that would have helped explain that a little more. For the sake of the movie I chalked it up to story-line progression...

Comment: @Odin1806 I don't think the Exterminator character is in the comics at all.  It's a much different plot.  We watched on HBO, so no deleted scenes & I couldn't find mention of it anywhere, but I will check the DVD sometime and see if there is anything.